# I want to crop image using C#

Tags: c#

I'm new to C#. I have no idea what's wrong... please fix the errors so that this code would work. I want to crop image using C#. When this code works, I'll study it.

https://ideone.com/ljkaWZ

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1

    public static Bitmap cropAtRect(this Bitmap b, Rectangle r)
{
    Bitmap nb = new Bitmap(r.Width, r.Height);
    Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(nb);
    g.DrawImage(b, -r.X, -r.Y);
    return nb;
}
```

ideone.com says:

```
prog.cs(13,10): error CS1514: Unexpected symbol `public', expecting `.' or `{'
prog.cs(13,18): error CS1525: Unexpected symbol `Bitmap', expecting `class', `delegate', `enum', `interface',      
`partial', or `struct'
Compilation failed: 2 error(s), 0 warnings
```

Comment: You should leran basic C# syntax. Create class, methods and so on

Comment: where is Your `Form ` Class

Comment: please just fix the errors, then I'll study every bit of it. I'm already familiar with class, methods, etc. co'z I have experience in Javascript

Comment: JavaScript and C# are not comparable. C# has a strict syntax and is truly OO. JavaScript is not as much

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is very low quality and doesn't show any effort

Answer (score 0):

If you want to crop an image, you can specify a `source` rectangle and a `destination` rectangle. In your case, `r` will be the source, and at the given sample below `destRect` will be the destination that will create the new bitmap.

```
public static Bitmap cropAtRect(Bitmap b, Rectangle r)
{
    Bitmap nb = new Bitmap(r.Width, r.Height);
    Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(nb);
    Rectangle destRect = new Rectangle(0, 0, r.Width, r.Height); //Set destination rect
    g.DrawImage(b, destRect, r, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
    return nb;
}
```

Of course you should validate if the given `r` (source rectangle) is within bounds of the `b` (source bitmap).

Also I am not sure if you are learning to create an `extension` method via `this`. But for now the above sample should work for cropping an image. Make sure to learn the proper syntax too.

Comment: You can use the code by invoking it: `cropAtRect(Bitmap, Rectangle)` Bitmap and Rectangle are your parameters.

Comment: can I run this not in visual studio?